# How can I hide a collectionView when scrolling in my tableView (knowing that this ViewCOntroller is half tableview and half collectionview)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So I have a `UIViewController` that have a `collectionView` with horizontal scrolling (like the facebook stories on the top of newsFeed page) and under it is the `tableView` with cells. How can I hide this collection view when I scroll down the `tableView`? I want it to exactly like facebook.

[image: so I have the stories on top as collectionViews]

Comment: Can you show us some little code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set collectionView height constraint, and when you begin dragging table view:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 0
```

You can know about start dragging from table view delegate. For this you should inherit your viewController from UITableViewDelegate and set a function :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("begin dragging")
    heightConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```